# Rails 4: mail_to helper adds HTML attribute target="_blank"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using `mail_to` helper method in the mailer views as follows,

`mail_to "test@example.com", "Contact Us"`

And it creates HTML as follows,

`<a href="mailto:test@example.com" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>`

This works fine as it opens default mailer application to draft the email.

But the issue is, due to it was added `target="_blank"` HTML attribute, unnecessary blank browser window opens.

I tried with no luck to find where it was added and how to prevent this. Please can anyone help out with this problem?

Comment: Are you viewing the generated output in a web-based mail app like Gmail? Is it possible that  your viewing application is appending the target attribute? Looking at the mail_to source (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c24659bf9963578f82173b00ee9dca087692ed25/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L456), I don't see anywhere that target is added.

Comment: @andrunix - Yes. I am viewing the generated output in a web browser. I am using `maicatcher` for email previews and got the issue here. And I am pretty sure that it is not adding in the application code.

Answer (score 0):

`mail_to` does not add `target="_blank"` by default. Most likely it is injected by some other portion of your code.

If you are too lazy to find the source, you can use this is a workaround

```
mail_to "test@example.com", "Contact Us", { target: '_self' }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is something I can try. And let's see if I find any clue on actual issue.